# SQL query involves three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database, I have three tables `students`, `classes`, `courses`.

One `class` has many `students`.

One `class` has many `courses`.

The `courses` table has one boolean field `active`, and a string field `name`.

The `students` table has `id` field.

So overall relationship is (sorry I am not sure how to better illustrate the relationship if it is not clear) :

```
students (many_to_one) classes (one_to_many) courses
```

I would like to write a SQL query to get the ids of `students` whose `courses` (via `class`) are within names `('foo', 'bar','etc')` and are `active`.

How to write this SQL ?

I tried :

```
select stu.id
from students stu
inner join classes clz ON clz.id = stu.class_id
inner join courses cour ON cour.class_id = clz.id
where cour.active=true 
and cour.name in ('foo', 'bar', 'etc');
```

Is it fine?

Comment: It would be better to write what have you tried because StackOverflow is not a free code source. You should know that with a reputation of 10.6k.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ---- 10.6K? Really?

Comment: Added what I tried

Comment: so what error are you getting?

Comment: My only extra question, do you want students who have all 3 classes? or just any student who have AT LEAST ONE of the classes you selected?  They are two completely different answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems ok except you used == instead of = in your inner joins clauses :

```
select stu.id
from students stu
inner join classes clz ON clz.id = stu.class_id
inner join courses cour ON cour.class_id = clz.id
where cour.active = true 
and cour.name in ('foo', 'bar', 'etc');
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a1c0ccfcfc1fe1192b726c1d46fd501f)

Comment: Are you sure this code works? because I have the same question as well.

Comment: How could I be sure without an MCRE (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ? I need a short sample example ...

Comment: Also it should be "select stu.id" since also classes has "id" value and it will receive ambiguous column name error.

Comment: You are completely right, I edit my answer and will provide a short example

Comment: @Masood I have added a little demo, if your data are ok, everything should work fine.

Comment: @Gosfly Thanks for the solution and Demo.

Comment: @Gosfly Thanks man you really helped me. It worked!